# Creating a github dashboard on portfolio site

Tags: node.js, reactjs, github-api

Thank you for giving me a piece of your time. This question really isn't a "how to", but more of a "is this possible or am I just insane?". I've recently looked at some portfolio pages and found a really great idea from https://flexdinesh.github.io/, but in the "portfolio" section instead of having just the characteristics of the project, is it possible to somehow use the Github API or some other equivalent to extract and present data like number of commits (or the table that github shows on your project page) and what project type it is (i.e. Java, Javascript, etc.) and maybe even some more related information. For background I am using React with Node.js. Again, this is probably useless to everyone out there, but I think it could be something cool if A) it actually exists, and B) it's not too much of a pain to implement. I've tried reading up on the documentation from Github, looking online, and looking at different source code, but no luck there. If anyone has any information or feedback I'm always open to help!

Thank you and have a good day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from what I understand, you want to display statistical information about the projects on your portfolio website.

Github provides an API that can get almost all the information you see on their website

so, to get all the languages being used in repository you can do a GET request on `https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/languages`,

To get the number of commits you can do a GET request on `https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/commits`
and so on

By default, these will get you the data of the public repositories, if you want to display info from your Private repositories, you need to provide an authentication token with each request.

You can read more about the API calls available [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/)

let me know if you need any more help

Comment: Thank you very much! Yeah basically that and basic characteristics of the project. I'll have a read. Thank you very much!